# Subquery returns more than 1 row in php

Tags: php, mysql

```
INSERT INTO orders( Copy_ID, CustID ) 
VALUES (
(

SELECT Copy_ID
FROM cart
), (

SELECT c.Cust_ID
FROM customers AS c, accounts AS a, cart AS ca
WHERE c.Cust_ID = a.Cust_ID
AND a.Username = ca.Customer
)
)
```

**i want to run this query through php, but mysql returns more than 1 row**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
INSERT INTO `orders` (`Copy_ID`,`Cust_ID`)
    SELECT `cart`.`CopyID`, `customers`.`CustID`
        FROM `customers`
        JOIN `accounts` USING (`Cust_ID`)
        JOIN `cart` ON `accounts`.`Username`=`cart`.`Customer`
```

Answer (score 0):

Because when you are doing

```
SELECT Copy_ID
FROM cart
```

the query is returning all the values of `Copy_ID` stored in `cart` and at the same time, the next query is returning a set too.

MySQL did not find a pair of values which should be INSERTed into the `orders` table.
You will have to fin a query in which you `INSERT` some specific set of value into the table.

Comment: the problem is, i want to take all the rows from the tables and insert them into table(cart)

Comment: you may try to do `SELECT copy_ID FROM cart WHERE Cust_ID = "xyz" //unique`. I mean to say that both the queries should return only one particular value.

Comment: What is there in `cart` ? and from which table you want to take values?

Comment: i want to insert into (orders.Copy_ID) all the rows from the column (cart.Copy_ID) and into (orders.CustID) all the rows from the column (cart.CustID)